# how to program alerts and warning messages using c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to program alerts and warning messages using c#.net

Comment: And what do you mean by "alerts and warning messages"? Is this something to warn/alert the *client*? operate at the *server*? (resources, etc) - and what form should this take? I think you could (and should) add a lot more detail here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web? Try this:

```
string textForMessage = @"<script language='javascript'> alert('test\ntest\ntest\ntest');</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "UserPopup", textForMessage);
```

Output

[image]

Got it [**here**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/85980-javascript-alert-from-code-behind/)